# Cross-platform virtual disk or volume

Tags: linux, cross-platform, hard-disk, virtualization, disk-image

Basically I need some software that can mount a virtual disk file as a disk or a volume file as a volume, that works for both Windows and Linux.

For example, Windows' built-in support for VHD files allows me to mount VHD files as virtual hard drives in Windows. Here I need a solution like this, but works for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Have you tried to [mount VHD](http://askubuntu.com/a/763548/269282) in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use VirtualBox fuse. It allows you to attach VHD images on Linux, this way you can mount VHD images on both Windows inbuilt support and also Linux using this package.

Here's a guide that will provide step by step instructions on how to install and use VirtualBox fuse, [Mounting VHD Image file in Linux](http://key-value.blogspot.com/2013/06/mounting-vhd-image-file-in-linux.html)

## VirtualBox FUSE

> VirtualBox is a free x86 virtualization solution allowing a wide range of x86 operating systems such as Windows, DOS, BSD or Linux to run on a Linux system.
>
> This package provides a FUSE-based VFS (Virtual FileSystem) to mount a VirtualBox disk so all partitions can be loop-mounted.